# Get id number from URL approach

Tags: regex, scala

I have simple `URL` and somewhere i have id that i want to get.
This `id` is inside this `string`:

```
...&userId=123&...
```

So I want to get the number `123`.

This is what I tried:

```
val url = "......"
val value = array.find(x => x.startsWith("userId="))
val id = value.get.replace("userId=", "")
```

Any other suggestions or this is the best approach?

Comment: [codereview.se] could be a better place to post the question if the code works fine

Comment: Use a simple regex approach: [`userId=([^&]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/wY9qK8/1)

Comment: Don't roll your own URL parser but use some package. For instance http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't Scala but what you are trying to do doesn't make sense to me. So if you like to do it with RegExes then this would be your choice. A good choice actually:

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/1p4hcU)

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object Main extends App {
    val url = "https://example.com/?foo=bar&userId=4523&foo=baz"
    val pattern = new Regex("userId=(\\d+)")
    pattern.findFirstMatchIn(url) match {
        case Some(m) => println(m.group(1))
    }
}
```

Comment: The ID could be alphanumeric, better use `userId=([^&]+)`

Comment: If it is numerical (like what OP shows) then it wouldn't contain alphabets.

Comment: And if the id was only latters ?

Comment: Then you should change it to `userId=([a-zA-Z]+)` @davidhol

Comment: @davidhol: With only l**e**tters, `userId=([^&]+)` would still work, as would ie `userId=([A-Za-z]+)` for english letters.

Comment: @Jan likes it more generic. I made it more specifically.